# SQL Server Query running slow when changing constant in where clause

Tags: sql, performance, constants, where-clause

Hello all and thanks in advance. I have a view that when queried with no where clause takes just over 0 seconds to return ~8600 rows. However, when I query with a where clause such as:

```
SELECT * FROM myView WHERE myID = 123
```

depending on what constant I put in place of 123 the query execution time changes considerably.

Now, "considerably" in this case means the difference between just above 0 seconds and 3 to 4 seconds.  But the view is called frequently and repeatedly for certain tasks which makes 3 seconds turn into 30 or more seconds.

While I cannot give the code for the view itself, what I can confirm is that:

1. The view is comprised of the joining of 6 standard tables (no special qualities).
2. While there may not always be records in table A that link up with table B, thus creating null columns in the results, I have confirmed that such instances are not consistently resulting in the longer or shorter query times.
3. The view itself has no clauses beyond the standard `Select`, `From`, and `Left Outer Join` clauses.
4. Certain IDs always result in long query times and the others always result in short query times
5. I have dropped and created the view in between queries on the off chance that there was a cached execution plan that was sub-optimal.

If these known variables are not enough to reduce the possibilities down to 2 or 3 possible causes I would still like to know what THEORETICAL problems might be causing this issue just to expand my understanding.

Thanks Again,

ProtoNoob

Comment: Are the indices on all of the tables that you derive your view from optimized for your queries and joins?

Comment: is it possible to show the script of your view (with changed table names, if it matters)?

Comment: What else is running on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the statistics for the tables are outdated and do not match the real content of the tables. This would mean that the optimizer, relying on the statistics, e. g. assumes that a value you use in the WHERE clause does not occur in the data at all, hence the result set being rather small, while in reality it contains many rows. Or the other way round: Relying on the statistics, the optimizer could assume that - say- 20% of the rows of the table have this value, and hence it is better to do a full table scan than to first access index pages for evaluating the where condition, then jump to a data page for almost each index entry to read the data, and in the end having to read nearly all pages anyway. Or it would access the tables in a wrong order, or ... But in reality, the value is not contained in the table at all, thus just leading to a wrong plan.

One hint pointing to outdated statistics would be if the query plan shows a huge difference between estimated and actual number of rows.

Which DBMS are you using? If SQL Server, then you can see the current statistics using  [`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174384.aspx) and refresh the statistics for selected columns and tables using the [`UPDATE STATISTICS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187348.aspx) statement. There are more views and procedures around this subject, most of them are linked from one of these two articles.